# How to see/trace Manipulate steps?

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, debugging, workbench

I am relatively new in Wolfram Language. What I want to solve is tracing "manipulate" steps in one of the demonstration project example codes. In my particular example, there are nearly 20 user build functions in a Manipulate function, some of them calls old Combinatorica' functions and also hosting many many long lists.

There is no detailed info about evaluating steps in a long "manipulate" code or at least I didn't find a usefull one. I know there are "trace" -"monitor" like functions but these are not effective in a long "Manipulate" cell.  After that since I've a little bit experinced in traditional programming so I wanted to trace branches of the programme by using an old fashioned way, you know via Wolfram Workbench in Eclipse, debug commands. But unfortunately, I guess I coudn't do it a right way. So cannot see evaluation steps in a "Manipulate" function and not see series of function calls and stacks.

I really wonder a way to solve "manipulate" evaluation steps. Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Can you not just copy the `Manipulate` source block and evaluate that step-by-step and inspect the result periodically?

Comment: I've already do that. But because of very intricate and spreading structure of code make it untraceable. So simply step by step evaluation approach not work as expected.

Comment: Nasser, Yes you are right bult-in debug is very sophisticated that avarage person can not use it correctly:). I also tried debug trace tool at the : http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/debugtrace/debugtrace.html. Normally in my opinion it is better than built-in debug option. But because of " Manipulate" function has so many parameter options, none of these debuggers can solve it correctly. And I'm gonna try "Print" may be it work. Thanks.